# WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost error with Selenium 3 and chromedriver on MacOS

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I have this weird issue. I am not able to run tests with chromedriver on my Mac. I have searched every possible corner here and none seems to help.
My browser is launched, but it freezes just before the `driver.get(url)` is called.

My environment:
MacOS High Sierra, Latest chromedriver as of 12March 2018, Latest selenium 3.10, Latest TestNG 6.14

My code:

```
public class Temp {

@Test()
public void test1() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/chromedriver");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--test-type");
    options.addArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

Exception I'm getting is:

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
>   Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307) on port 34979
>   [warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
>   Mar 12, 2018 7:06:13 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   FAILED: test1
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:34979
>   Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:03:16.397Z'
>   System info: host: 'sandeep-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.0.100', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
>   Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.maximize(RemoteWebDriver.java:892)
>     at com.pareek.framework.tests.Temp.test1(Temp.java:22)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
>     at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:34979
>     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:240)
>     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:158)
>     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
>     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
>     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
>     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
>     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
>     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
>     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
>     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
>     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:101)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:157)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>     ... 29 more
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>     at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:125)
>     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:238)
>     ... 49 more
>
> ===============================================
>
> > Default test
> >
> > ## > Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
>
> ===============================================
>   Default suite
>
> ## Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Edit: If I remove comment out `driver.manage().window().maximize();` function, the exception log is as below:

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
>   Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307) on port 22528
>   [warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
>   Mar 12, 2018 7:29:29 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   FAILED: test1
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"8045B2382F1BD52FB2B8744951B53B43","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
>     (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.146)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248307,platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:03:16.397Z'
>   System info: host: 'sandeep-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.0.100', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {userDataDir: /var/folders/3t/p4sy21xx2cb...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, nativeEvents: true, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, version: 65.0.3325.146, webStorageEnabled: true}
>   Session ID: 2301d210d1a4f56bab558a8111d856c4
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
>     at com.pareek.framework.tests.Temp.test1(Temp.java:24)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
>     at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> ===============================================
>
> > Default test
> >
> > ## > Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
>
> ===============================================
>   Default suite
>
> ## Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
>
> Additional Info:
>   I have tried to do a regression by using older version of chromedriver, older version of TestNG, older version of selenium, but none seems to be working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2 Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307) on port 34979 
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0 Mar 12, 2018 7:06:13 AM 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession 
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS FAILED: test1
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:34979 
Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:03:16.397Z' 
System info: host: 'sandeep-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.0.100', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=v2.9*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.9*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v31-34**

- Your *Chrome Browser* version is unknown to us. (assuming Chrome Browser is updated to v65.x level)
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.10.0**.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_101** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u101* , *Selenium Client v3.10.0* , *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.9*) and the current *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Keep *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.10.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  stable [**ChromeDriver v2.36**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v65.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.36 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Chrome* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of Chrome.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Thank you for quick help over this. I tried multiple things except pointing eclipse to my current Java. I will give it a try and keep this thread posted.

Comment: Updating to Chromedriver 2.36 solved my issue. I have marked your answer as 'Accepted'. Thanks!